# Replace multiple String with multiple Variable

Tags: php, mysql

I Want change all Strings starting with `{" and ending with "}` to a variable, 
for *example:*

```
Hello {username}, -> to Hello $array['username']
Your Country is {country}, -> Your Country is $array['country']
```

But i get all strings text from database with one variable (Mysql) With `$array['content']`

What I Want:

```
str_replace("{$whatinhere}",$array['$copytohere'],$array['content']);

str_replace("{company}",$array['company'],$array['content']);
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I understand you're confused, but that doesn't mean your question has to be that too. Try to start with an example of your input, and the wanted output. Tell us why you need that transformation. Then show us what you have tried, and tell us what your problem is.

Comment: I know, My English is bad, I Have This Text >
---
Hello {username}, Your Country is {country}. Your Age is {age}. You are {gender}
---

I want change this {whatishere} to $array['tohere'];

Comment: Your English is not the problem, I think. Try to edit your question.

Comment: If you don’t know what potential placeholders you _could_ have, then this is not a job for str_replace to begin with. Then you’d need to use regular expressions to do a pattern search.

Comment: As @KIKOSoftware suggested, edit your answer, to have the input you have, what you do with that input and then what you get as an output and what you expect to have as an output.

Comment: Pls give names of all values between "{" and "}" that need to replaced with variables. Also give the names of the variables

Comment: All values between {and} is much more, names of the variables also same

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I dont Get Errors. I want copy values between { and } and put it to variables ($array['here']), Because I Have more this And I Want to write this with single condes, not copying same code 100 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preg_replace_callback function

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~{(.+?)}~', 
        function($x) use ($array) { return isset($array[$x[1]]) ? $array[$x[1]] : ''; }, 
        $array['content']);
```

Comment: Yes It Is Worked FIne, Thank You. You are save me ) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this...

```
$content = $array['content'];

$mainContent = str_replace('{username}', $array['username'], $content);

$mainContent = str_replace('{company}', $array['company'], $mainContent);

echo $mainContent;
```

Comment: This is certainly an improvement, you're using the result of `str_replace()`. Whether it actually does what is needed is questionable, but it could.

Comment: Yes I Want this, but can i use this with one line code ? or it is not possible ? 

Because The names are same, not different. I want 100-200 {changes}. It is possible ?

Comment: So you can use looping by creating array of all named variables

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the `$array` variable contains the placeholder key/value pairs and also the content. You can try following code for replacing all placeholder keys with their corresponding values:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != "content") {
        $array["content"] = str_replace("{" . $key . "}", $value, $array["content"]);
    }
}

/** Print contents */
echo $array["content"];
```

Comment: Thank You, But not worked for me. Because I cant use loop function